# Как вычисляется "ожидаемое значение" в протоколе PPP CHAP?

Tags: алгоритм, сеть, авторизация, шифрование

Есть [RFC 1994](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1994) с описанием протокола CHAP, где утверждается про вычисление "ожидаемого значения" на авторизующем сервере на основе данных из запроса пользователя. Но в данном RFC нет описания про способ вычисления оного.

Отсюда вопрос: для протокола CHAP используются один или несколько способов вычисления "ожидаемого значения", если один, то какой именно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там есть описание алгоритма

> The Response Value is the one-way hash calculated over a stream of
>   octets consisting of the Identifier, followed by (concatenated   with)
>   the "secret", followed by (concatenated with) the Challenge   Value. 
>   The length of the Response Value depends upon the hash   algorithm
>   used (16 octets for MD5).

**Response Value** - это результат вычисления хэш-функции над массивом байт состоящим из **идентификатора**, **секрета** и **запроса** (**Challenge**). Длина значения ответа зависит от алгоритма хэш-функции (16 байт для MD5).